A supernatural toy airplane
I had watched this movie on tv when I was small. It's neither an animated nor a cartoon movie.
The story of the movie goes like this. There was a child who liked bicycles. So he asked for a bicycle from his father. But his father gave him a toy airplane instead, for his birthday may be. This boy didn't like it. He was upset about it and he put the toy bicycle away on the cupboard. A few days later his father died. One day this child saw his airplane flying in a dream. But soon he realized it was not a dream. He climbed to roof and tried to fly. His mom saw it and got frightened. Mom got angry and opened a window and threw the airplane. Immediately this airplane came back into house breaking windows and lights.
This is the beginning story. I want to know the movie title.

Always important for such questions: When have you been "small"? It could have been 5, 10, 15, 20, ... years ago or maybe you're a midget (no offense!).

Sounds like Cédric Kahn's L'avion from 2005:

Charly wishes a bicycle with all his heart for Christmas. Therefore his disappointment is bigger, when his father presents him a self-built plane. But after his father's death, the plane develops to an own life, further it becomes Charly's new friend and helps him to stand his father's death with magical adventures. 

Here's the trailer, and it also contains the scenes you're describing (the roof scene and the airplane breaking lights and windows on its own):




yes yes this is the movie.nice ..thank
